# Excel evaluating text strings in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to search a cell which contains a string that can have a number of key words, singular and together, and assign a value depending on which words are present.

These are the key words that may appear in the cell and the value I want to return/assign using a formula.

"Growth" - return "1"

"Income" - return "0.5"

"Borderline" - return "0.5"

"Borderline" and "Income" - return "1"

"Non Star" - return "0"

I've developed this formula which works for all strings except those that contain "Borderline" AND "Income" in the one cell.

=IF(ISBLANK($A1),"",IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Growth",$A1)),"1",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Income",$A1)),"0.5",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Borderline",$A1)),"0.5",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Non Star",$A1)),"0"))

I've developed an AND() formula that caters for the strings that contain Borderline AND Income but can't see how to incorprate that into my main formula.

=IF(AND(COUNT(SEARCH("Income",$A1))>0,COUNT(SEARCH("Borderline",$A1))>0),"1","")

Can anyone help me out? Needless to say it's becoming very complex/confusing so maybe there's a better way overall?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that has the words and values besides. Then use this table as a lookup range.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the `1` for "borderline" and "income" is just the sum of "borderline" `0.5` and "income", so you could handle it with the extra "borderline income" line.
For example this:

> ***Note*** It's an array-formula which needs to be confirmed through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$1:$C$4,A1)),$D$1:$D$4)),"")
```

or without extra table

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Growth","Income","Borderline","Non Star"},A1)),{1,0.5,0.5,0})),"")
```

Put this in `B1` and pull it down. Be aware though, that this formula sums up all values of corresponding occurences, as can be seen in line 5. If this behaviour isn't wanted, just tell me and i will try to change the formula accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the table approach is a much better approach but for me collapsing it a formula without a table works best. Thank you both!